# Graph API: Sharing a friend's post on my wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-wall

Using the Graph API, how do I share a friend's post on my own wall ?
I don't want to copy the original post's text and create a new post, becuase I need my friend to see that I shared his post.

The post on my wall should look like this[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing a post from the API isn't possible - you can only re-post it using the same information, but it would effectively be a new post and wouldn't say who it was shared from (unless you add it manually in the caption, e.g. Someone shared ... via Someone).

Comment: Thanks. How can I make sure my friend will know I "shared" his post ? I want to leave some kind of notice on his news stream